# jquery add class img depending of anchor value

Tags: jquery, html, class, addition

i have this html code:

```
<a href="/book/YYYY-MM-DD">
<div class="BW">
    <div class="BB">
        <div class="BC">
            <div class="icon"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="BIMG">

        </div>
        <div class="BW">
            <div class="BD">
            </div>
            <div class="BB">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

I Want to add a class to div .BIMG depending of href value

i have this jquery code:

```
jQuery("a[href*=/book/2016-11-16]").addClass("color");
```

but i cant get it

could you please help me

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to match numbers or a general pattern, but I think you need quotes: `jQuery('a[href*="/book/2016-11-16"]')

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty click event to accomplish this:

```
$("a[href*=/book/2016-11-16]").on('click', function () {
    $(".BIMG").addClass("color");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each occurrence of `.BIMG` on the page. For each, find the closest (parent) `a` which matches on the `href` you supplied.

If anything is found that satisfies that `href`, add the class `color` to `.BIMG`.

```
$('.BIMG').each(function() {
    $a = $(this).closest('a[href*=/book/2016-11-16]');
    if ($a.length) {
       $(this).addClass("color");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynv6sd5h/2/) of the code above in action.